# How to identify a mobile device with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile

I'm developing a website for mobile devices. In order to log behavior of users I want to save `ID cookie` of the user on the client. When a user revisits my website I can read the `ID cookie` to identify the user.

On some devices that works fine because the device automatically accepts saving the `ID cookie`. But some devices (eg. iPhone) that doesn't work.

How can I uniquely identify a mobile device (eg. by MAC address?).

I can only run JavaScript on the mobile device.

Comment: Whether or not user agents accept cookies is unrelated to whether they are mobile, fixed  or whatever. If the client doesn't accept cookies, tell them the benefits they'll get if they turn them on. If they choose not to, that's their choice.

Comment: Exactly @RobG. But most of users of my site don't have understanding of mobile setting and english. Therefore I want do It automatic.

Comment: I doubt you can get a unique identifier (like MAC) for the device just using javascript in a web page. If you could, I think users would not be very happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** this, Might work in your case :)

```
    var macAddress = "";
    var ipAddress = "";
    var computerName = "";
    var wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}");
    e = new Enumerator(wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True"));
    for(; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
        var s = e.item(); 
        macAddress = s.MACAddress;
        ipAddress = s.IPAddress(0);
        computerName = s.DNSHostName;
    }
```

Comment: I think this code runs in PC. That I need is runs in mobile device(iphone, android)